# How to test an AnimatedIcon in Flutter

Tags: flutter, widget, widget-test-flutter

I want to do a test that allows me to verify if my widget is showing the `AnimatedIcon` that I provide, as well as to know if the animation is working (changing the icon in an animated way), the problem is that I can't find the way to do it.

1. Is there a method similar to `finder.byIcon()`, but that accepts `AnimatedIconData` instead of `IconData`?
2. How to verify that the animation is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1. Finder for AnimatedIconData

To get a finder for `AnimatedIconData`, use the [find.byWidgetPredicate](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/CommonFinders/byWidgetPredicate.html) method like below (assuming the `AnimatedIconData` being searched for is `AnimatedIcons.menu_arrow`):

```dart
final animatedIconFinder = find.byWidgetPredicate((widget) =>
        widget is AnimatedIcon && widget.icon == AnimatedIcons.menu_arrow);
```

### 2. Verification that the animation is happening

To verify that the animation is happening, check the value of the [AnimatedIcon](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AnimatedIcon-class.html) widget's [progress](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AnimatedIcon/progress.html) property.

Assuming the animation happens after a floating action button on the screen is tapped, the code sample below shows how to verify that the `AnimatedIcon` animates after the button is tapped.

```dart
// Gets the [AnimatedIcon] widget
final animatedIconWidget = tester.widget(animatedIconFinder) as AnimatedIcon;

final animatedIconProgress = animatedIconWidget.progress.value;

// Verifies that [AnimatedIcon] is not animating
expect(animatedIconProgress, 0);

// Finds [FloatingActionButton]
final floatingActionButtonFinder = 
    find.widgetWithIcon(FloatingActionButton, Icons.change_circle);

// Taps [FloatingActionButton]
await tester.tap(floatingActionButtonFinder);

await tester.pumpAndSettle();

final updatedAnimatedIconProgress = animatedIconWidget.progress.value;

// Verifies that the [AnimatedIcon] has completed its animation
expect(updatedAnimatedIconProgress, 1);
```

### Using a Custom Finder

To make your finder more concise and similar to [find.byIcon](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/CommonFinders/byIcon.html), do the following:

1. Create a custom Finder by extending [MatchFinder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/MatchFinder-class.html) and add the matching logic in the `matches` method (This is a modification of the [find.byIcon](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/12cb4eb7a009f52b347b62ade7cb4854b926af72/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/finders.dart#L211) [implementation](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/12cb4eb7a009f52b347b62ade7cb4854b926af72/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/finders.dart#L829-L842)).

   ```dart
   class _WidgetAnimatedIconFinder extends MatchFinder {
     _WidgetAnimatedIconFinder(this.icon, {super.skipOffstage});

     final AnimatedIconData icon;

     @override
     String get description => 'icon "$icon"';

     @override
     bool matches(Element candidate) {
       final Widget widget = candidate.widget;
       return widget is AnimatedIcon && widget.icon == icon;
     }
   }
   ```
2. Create an extension on the [CommonFinders](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/CommonFinders-class.html) class and add a `byAnimatedIcon` method that uses the custom Finder created in step 1. The CommonFinders class is provided by the [flutter_test](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/flutter_test-library.html) package and the [find](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/find-constant.html) constant (as in `find.byIcon`) is an instance of `CommonFinders`.

   ```dart
   extension CustomFindersExtension on CommonFinders {
     Finder byAnimatedIcon(AnimatedIconData icon) =>
       _WidgetAnimatedIconFinder(icon);
   }
   ```
3. Use `find.byAnimatedIcon` to find the AnimatedIcon by supplying the `AnimatedIconData` being searched for.

   Replace the `Finder` using `find.byWidgetPredicate` with this below:

   ```dart
   final animatedIconFinder = find.byAnimatedIcon(AnimatedIcons.menu_arrow);
   ```

Comment: I's works. Just remplace `expect(animatedIconProgress, 1);
` by `expect(updatedAnimatedIconProgress , 1);
` to by accepted

Comment: @devblock, updated. Thanks for catching that. Glad to know it works!